# Sorting a Stack in Ascending Order?

Tags: c, sorting, stack, dynamic-programming

What is the best method for **sorting a stack in ascending order? I** came across this interview question, and I was running into some problems for the best and most efficient solution.

There are two methods that I can think of.

1. To pop all the contents of the stack and store them in an array, and then sort the array in
   `O(nLog n)` and then push the contents back the stack. Not the best way....
2. Do the recursive implementation of the stack for sorting it

```
void sort(stack)
{
    type x;

    if (!isEmpty(stack)) {
        x = pop(stack);
        sort(stack);
        insert(x, stack);
    }           
}

void insert(x, stack)
{
    type y;

    if (!isEmpty(stack) && top(stack) < x) {
        y = pop(stack);
        insert(x, stack);
        push(y, stack);
    } 
    else {
        push(x, stack);
    }
}
```

But the 2nd method seems to be making too many recursive calls and the overhead will be a problem if the stack happens to be really big.

Is it possible to solve this problem in a much better way for the best space and time complexity?

There are so many recursive calls, (overlapping subproblems), is this a contender for `dynamic programming` type of problems?

What would be the best way to solve this? ?

Comment: Why is `O(n*log n)` sorting time suboptimal? For the general case, that is the proven limit.

Comment: You can't do better than `O(n)` space and `O(n log n)` time. Popping into an array, sorting and pushing is optimal.

Comment: @avakar: Got a proof for the first claim ("can't do better than `O(n)` space")?

Comment: @aix, sure, just put the smallest (or the largest, I'm not sure which element in the stack is the first) value at the bottom of the stack. You'll have to pop that value out as it is in the wrong spot and at that point, you'll have to have those `n` values stored somewhere, requiring `O(n)` space.

Comment: This is a bad interview question. A stack is a last in, first out data structure. If you need an ordered container then use a different data structure. If you insist on "sorting a stack" then expose the internal implementation and sort the underlying container.

Comment: @Blastfurnace - Or, it is good interview question, the correct answer for which is, "if you need an ordered container then use a different data structure."

Answer (score 3):

It's a stack.  You can't see anything but the top value.  You'll have to pop everything at least once, and push everything at least once.  The first method is fine.

If the stack operations are expensive but you have a time deadline, use insertion sort as you're popping and you can push as soon as your last pop is done.  But you're saying this is in C++ so I doubt we are considering such a scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve by eliminating the recursion. For this you just use a loop iterating under a stack until it is empty.

For example, pseudo code:

```
Linekd Stack stack = new List ();

while stack is not empty then

     element <- stack removes peek

     / / Recursiong
     push new elements on stack

end
```

Comment: You can simulate a recursion with iteration loop and stack data structure.

Comment: Is it not the same ? Recursion makes function calls go on the stack memory, and it is just the same implementation.

Comment: When you use recursion native language, there is a need to pile up a lot more than just data, it is necessary to stack the context, function pointers, etc.. If you use a stack data structure, depending on the volume of the stacked data, you will get an optimum use of memory.

Answer (score -1):

This problem  cant have complexity less than O(n^2). For further reference refer [here](http://puddleofriddles.blogspot.in/2011/04/sort-stack-in-ascending-order-when.html)

Comment: Please refer to the question again. (1) accomplishes this already.

Comment: "This algorithm will have a time complexity of O(N^2)." doesn't mean that O(N^2) is optimal and in this case it is trivial to accomplish it in O(N lg N) as described in the question itself!